# Getting past the 200 inch adobe error with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am converting a multi-paged (paginated) pdf document into a single page (non-paginated) pdf document.
I am looking to overcome the 200 inch limitation in adobe reader.

With iTextSharp.PdfReader each page is read to create a total height of the target document and find the maximum width.

The code to create the document works ok reading directly from the paginated pdf into the non-paginated pdf.  Utilizing Chrome or Foxit the file opens fine.  Adobe gives the 200 inch truncation when the page exceeds 200 inchs.  In my test file the page height is 8.25 x 814 inches.

Changing the UserUnits to 4.07  (814/200) has Adobe show the page height as 814in but still truncates the page as well as showing the width as 33.

If the width of the target file is set to width/userunits (8.25/4.07) the only left 2 inches are shown in the target file.

The copy part of the code:

```
RandomAccessFileOrArray ra = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fn);

SizeF pageSize = new SizeF(pageWidth, pageHeight);
float USERUnitNewValue = ComputeUserUnit(pageSize);

if (pageHeight > 14400f)  
{
    USERUnitNewValue = pageHeight / 14400f;
}

float NewPageWidth = (pageWidth <= 14400f) ? pageWidth :  pageWidth* USERUnitNewValue;
float NewPageHeight = pageHeight * USERUnitNewValue;

FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(newfn);
DirectoryInfo directory1 = file1.Directory;
if (!directory1.Exists)
    directory1.Create();


iTextSharp.text.Rectangle newPagesize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(pageWidth, pageHeight);

Document newPdf = new Document(newPagesize);

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(newPdf, new FileStream(newfn, FileMode.Create));
writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_6;

if (pageHeight > 14400)
{
    writer.Userunit = USERUnitNewValue;
}
newPdf.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
newPdf.Open();

PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

float verticalPosition = pageHeight;
for (int pagenumber = 1; pagenumber <= n1; pagenumber++)
{
    if (pdfReader.NumberOfPages >= pagenumber)
    {
        verticalPosition = verticalPosition - pdfReader.GetPageSize(pagenumber).Height;
        cb.AddTemplate(writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, pagenumber), 0, verticalPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

newPdf.Close();
```

How can the original file be copied into the target where both files would keep the same size if someone sends it to a printer?

Yes there is some redundancy in this code as I have been troubleshooting this for a little while now.

The key question here is a setting that would maintain the 8.25 x 814in and still allow adobe to open the file.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Why would you use UserUnits like this? The value is supposed to scale both width and height of a page. The normal way of using it would be to generate the PDF for example at 1/10th of the size by setting both width and height of your PDF to 1/10 of what you want and then setting the UserUnit value to 10. In the Sign & Display market (or LFP if you prefer) this is how it is normally used, with the value either 2, 10 or even 64.

Comment: David,  If I'm using AddTemplate how would I scale it down when pulling from the original?

Comment: My question would be, how would I go about generating the PDF 1/10th the size of the original pdf document?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you David.
After looking through Mr Lowagie's document and brief note about addTemplate.
cb.addTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0)
The code was updated to utilize the new userunit and scaling.

Opening ok in Adobe now and reporting page length as expected

Once again the code is a little ugly still

```
            RandomAccessFileOrArray ra = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fn);

            SizeF pageSize = GetPageSize(fn);
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fn);

            float USERUnitNewValue = ComputeUserUnit(pageSize);
            int n1 = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;

            if (pageSize.Height > 14400f)  //14400 value is 72 pixels per inch over 200 inches.  200 inches seems to be adobe limit to a page
            {  //determine the userunit to be used
                USERUnitNewValue = pageSize.Height / 14400f;
            }

            float NewPageWidth = (pageSize.Width <= 14400f) ? pageSize.Width / USERUnitNewValue : pageSize.Width / USERUnitNewValue;
            float NewPageHeight = pageSize.Height / USERUnitNewValue;

            FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(newfn);
            DirectoryInfo directory1 = file1.Directory;
            if (!directory1.Exists)
                directory1.Create();

            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle newPagesize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(NewPageWidth, NewPageHeight);

            Document newPdf = new Document(newPagesize);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(newPdf, new FileStream(newfn, FileMode.Create));
            writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_6;

            if (pageSize.Height > 14400)
            {
                writer.Userunit = USERUnitNewValue;
            }
            newPdf.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
            newPdf.Open();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            float verticalPosition = NewPageHeight;
            for (int pagenumber = 1; pagenumber <= n1; pagenumber++)
            {
                if (pdfReader.NumberOfPages >= pagenumber)
                {
                    /*convoluted page position.  First position should be 0,0
                     unlike other counters this starts as page 1 so we need to subtract the
                     first page height away so that we start at the bottom of the previous image
                     * hmm  seems that ths AddTemplate feature adds the pages in reverse order or 
                     * at least the coordinate system sets 0,0 at the bottom left of the page
                     */
                    float widthfactor = 1 / USERUnitNewValue;  //Page scaling (width)
                    float heightfactor = 1 / USERUnitNewValue; //Page scaling (height)
                    //vertical position needs to take into account the new page height taking new UserUnit in affect
                    verticalPosition = verticalPosition - (pdfReader.GetPageSize(pagenumber).Height / USERUnitNewValue);

                    cb.AddTemplate(writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, pagenumber), heightfactor, 0, 0, widthfactor, 0, verticalPosition);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            newPdf.Close();
```

Thank you again for your help,
Mike